# SonarQube analysis in TFS Build fails after SonarQube upgrade

Tags: sonarqube

We are upgrading our SonarQube server from 6.1 to the 6.7.1 LTS.  We are running TFS 2017 on-prem.  I have updated the plugins to:
sonar-csharp - v 6.7.1.4347
sonar-css  v 4.5
sonar-ldap - v 2.2.0.608
sonar-scm-git - v  1.3.0.869
sonar-scm-tfvc v 2.1.2
sonar-typescript - v 1.1.0.1079
sonar-web - v 2.5.0.476
sonar-xml v 1.4.3.1027

When running a build the complete analysis step fails Post-processing failed. Exit code :1

there are warning messages about sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPath property is missing.
And 
"No roslyn issues report not found for this project"

Also, it suggests that I re-run the scanner using the -X switch.  but I haven't been able to find how to add that switch.

Any help on how to determine what/where the error is would be SUPER helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU/fixforversion/14193/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel) and [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU/fixforversion/13995/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel) releasenotes. Check if you are using the latest [scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) version: 4.0.2.892.

Comment: I put the latest version of the scanner in on the TFS Build Task, but it didn't change the behavior of the build.. it runs the new version of the scanner, but the same error comes. Interestingly,  If I run the command line commands to build and scan, the scan succeeds.. I looked to see if there was a newer version of the build task, but it doesn't look like there is

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the SonarQube API being called in the build step happened to start failing on special characters that it had not had trouble with before.  We were using curly-braces in our sonarQube project names, and the newer version really did not like that. Once we changed the project names to use parenthesis instead of the curly-braces, things were working better